# how to save qtablewidget data into excel file using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, pyqt5, openpyxl, qtablewidget

I have a qtablewidet that has data and when the user clicks the export button a dialog will appear asking for filename to save as excel, how do i do that using openpyxl?

here is my code

```
self.exportbtn.clicked.connect(self.export)

    def export(self):
        try:
            filename = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Save file', '','Excel files(*.xlsx)')
            wb = Workbook()
            sheet = wb.active
            for column in range(self.tableWidget.columnCount()):
                for row in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount()):
                    try:
                        text = str(self.tableWidget.item(row, column).text())
                        sheet.write(row, column, text)
                        wb.save(filename)
                    except Exception as e:
                        print("Error Writing file.")
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error Saving file.")
```

when i try to click save from the dialog, the output right now is this

[image]

how do i save the whole data including the headers from qtablewidget to an excel file using openpyxl?

update:
i edited my code now and i am able to create the file but the data from the qtablewidget is still not written in the excel file

```
def export(self):
        filename, filter = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Save file', '','Excel files (*.xlsx)')
        wb = Workbook()
        sheet = wb.active
        if not filename:
            for column in range(self.tableWidget.columnCount()):
                for row in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount()):
                    try:
                        text = str(self.tableWidget.item(row, column).text())
                        sheet.write(row, column, text)                    
                    except AttributeError:
                        pass
        wb.save(filename)
```

i tried printing the data from the qtablewidget and it shows, it just doesn't save in the excel file, is there still something missing?

Comment: change to `print("Error Writing file.", e)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your line wb.save(filename) is inside your for loop, thereby the same filename is being saved on every loop.

Move that line outside and after the for loops at the outer indentation and therefore save it only once.

Also, ensure that the filename does not already exist, else you may get a pop dialog "Are you sure?" and you then need to force save it.

Comment: but when i move it outside it says ```AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'write'```

Comment: I would expect you have to check what values you are getting from the qtablewidget.

Comment: I would expect you have to check what values you are getting from the qtablewidget to ensure sure you are not getting an invalid (null) value. Use a print to verify that the values are valid. Furthermore, the following lines you could use to save the values to excel, and you already have most of them in your code. 

from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()
sheet = wb.active

#in the for loops, get reference of cell, and assign data value
cellref = sheet.cell(row=4,column=5)
cellref.value = 'your data for the cell'

#after the for loops
wb.save('samplefile.xlsx')

Comment: i am now able to create the .xlsx file but the data from the qtable is not written into the file, i tried printing the values in the qtablewidget and it shows, it just doesnt save into the excel file, sorry i didnt quite get the get reference of cell part?

Comment: Your issue may not be with saving to excel, but just to be sure. Start by simply testing that you can save a simple string to excel, using your code to just simply enter a value in a cell, like this.# get the reference of cell 
cellref = sheet.cell(row=4,column=5)

# assign a value to the cell
cellref.value = 'test hello world'

#after the for loops
wb.save('samplefile.xlsx')

Comment: i edited my question and put my recent code now, i also did the simple test and it worked, maybe something is missing with my code now????

Comment: sheet.cell(3,3).value = 'hello world'      this would get the reference of the cell and enter the string 'hello world' in the excel cell C3

Comment: change the line: sheet.write(row, column, text)     and make it sheet.cell(row,column).value = text

Comment: your first index from the for loop is 0. However, in excel the spreadsheet starts from 1. Therefore, you need  to change the cell entry line to this:   sheet.cell(row+1,column+1).value = text

#Unfortunately, if you don't print the error message, it will be difficult for you to identify issues. You should not have a Pass in the exception part of your code as you are better off knowing when there is an issue. It is better to print out the error message and try to solve from there.

Comment: you have the line of code which you have added in your edit update which is not needed:

if not filename:

Comment: ahhhhh i see... i added the if not filename earlier coz its not creating the file, but i removed now  and replaced the sheet.cell(row+1,column+1).value = text, it works now, i just need to add the column headers, thank you very much for being patient with me :D

Answer (score 0):

Almost all static methods of QFileDialog (except for `getExistingDirectory()` and `getExistingDirectoryUrl()`) return a tuple in the form of `(file(s), filter)`.

For `getOpenFileNames()` (note the plural) the first object is a list of strings indicating the selected files, in the other cases it's the file path as a string or URL.

Do note that if the dialog is canceled, the file string (or the list) is empty, so you should check that before going on with the file writing:

```
    filename, filter = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(
        self, 'Save file', '','Excel files(*.xlsx)')
    if not filename:
        return
    # ...
```

Also, you should not try to save the file at each cycle of the for loop.

<sub>While 99% of the functions in Qt behave in the same way in PyQt, that's not always true, especially for situations for which C++ uses referenced variables. Whenever you are not sure about a function or get unexpeted behavior from it, you can check the [PyQt documentation](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/api/qtwidgets/qfiledialog.html) (the returned type(s) are specified at the end of the function definition, after the →) or just call `help(class.function)` in the python consolle. An even simpler solution is to just `print` the returned value, and you'll see that for yourself.</sub>

Comment: i am now able to create the xlsx file and it saves but when i open it, there is no data saved and empty, is there something missing in the for loop or something? i also have moved the wb.save outside

Answer (score 0):

```
def imag_Export_Report(self):  
    self.cur.execute('''SELECT name, phone, image FROM photo''')
    rows = self.cur.fetchall()
    excel_file = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "save file",'./','Excel Files (*.xlsx)')
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(excel_file[0])
    sheet1 = workbook.add_worksheet()
    sheet1.write(0, 0, 'name ') 
    sheet1.write(0, 1, ' phone')
    sheet1.write(0, 2, 'image ')

    row_number = 1  
    for row in rows:
        column_number = 0  
        for item in row:
            sheet1.write(row_number, column_number, str(item))
            column_number += 1
        row_number += 1
    workbook.close()
    self.con.commit()
```

Comment: In order for the data to be displayed in the Excel file, you must call the required data from the database